# how to add dependency array to a component did mount in react class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-class-based-component

> hi i am using react class component and would want to know that is it
> possible to create a dependency array for component Did Mount, like in
> use Effect

Comment: I could not find anything to solve this, however I realised that my belief that I needed to use a class component was actually false - a functional component worked fine and I was able to use useEffect

Answer (score 0):

As per React Docs,

1. If you need to run some logic everytime the component re-renders (state change or prop change) - use the **componentDidUpdate** method ([React Docs](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)).
   This emulates the same behaviour as `useEffect(someCallback)`
2. If you need to reset some state whenever a props changes - use the key prop. Everytime the key changes, react will create a new component, and as per component lifecycle, the logic inside the constructor will run again. (It's not necessary for the key to be used in Array.map) Check out this [url](https://legacy.reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-uncontrolled-component-with-a-key)
3. Lifecycle methods like **componentDidMount** will help emulate the same behaviour as `useEffect(someCallback, [])`

Reference - [React Docs - getDerivedStateFromProps](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops)

useEffect also allows us to set a cleanup function for clearing timers and whatnot. These activities can be done inside the **componentWillUnmount** method ([React Docs](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillunmount))